# C# Lists and interfaces

Tags: c#

I would like to pass a method a List of a custom type that conforms to an interface. I'd like the method parameter to be a List of the particular interface type.

Is this possible? I can see I can do this if I use an array instead of a List. I've added my code below to help clarify my problem.

```
public interface TeamMoveCTRL_IF
{
}

public class TeamMember:  TeamMoveCTRL_IF
{
}

public class TeamCTRL
{
    public TeamMember[] team1;
    public List<TeamMember> team2;
    void Start()
    {
        TestArray(team1); //Works
        TestListElement(team2[0]); //Works
        TestList(team2); //Error because team2 is List<TeamMember>
    }

    private void TestList(List<TeamMoveCTRL_IF> team )
    {
    }

    private void TestArray(TeamMoveCTRL_IF[] team)
    {
    }

    private void TestListElement(TeamMoveCTRL_IF member)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to pass single element to the function which expects list of elements?

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant (as well as any other class)

Comment: `TestList<T>(List<T> team) where T : TeamMoveCTRL_IF` or `TestList(IEnumerable<TeamMoveCTRL_IF> team)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
private void TestList<T>(IEnumerable<T> team)
where T : TeamMember
{
}
```

Instead of this two implementations:

```
private void TestList(List<TeamMoveCTRL_IF> team )
{
}

private void TestArray(TeamMoveCTRL_IF[] team)
{
}
```

Comment: Actually since `IEnumerable<T>` is co-variant just `TestList(IEnumerable<TeamMember> team)` would work.  You only really need to make it generic if you still pass `List<T>` instead.

Comment: @juharr, agreed, strange question)

Comment: why strange? I wanted a method with a parameter type of List<Interface>. That I can call and pass a List of a type that conforms to that interface. Now I know to use IEnumerable instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowed. Consider this:

```
interface I {}
class A : I {}
class B : I {}

void Fn(List<I> lst) =>
    lst.Add(new B());

static void Main() =>
    Fn(new List<A>());
```

If you were allowed to change the type of the parameter to a list of its interface, you'd be allowed to add anything derived from that interface in the list, whereas the original definition only allows `A` elements. You'd be breaking the definition of the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is not correct.
There are multiple ways to achieve what you need but it depends on context.

Start from following change and go from there.

```
    public List<TeamMoveCTRL_IF> team2;
```